# Can the `App` component have its state in the constructor and simultaneously fetch data from` store` in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Can the `App` component have its state in the constructor and simultaneously fetch data from`store` in redux? I am asking because if I remove `connect` and`mapStateToProps`, `this.state.tasks.filter` works normally. And when I add `connect` and`mapStateToProps`, I have the error `filter` is not function.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        tasks: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    const filterTasks = this.state.tasks.filter........

    return (
      <ul>

      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const {todos} = state;

  return {
    todos
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `mapStateToProps` functions give the value from `redux` store as props to the component `App`

inside `App` you can get redux `state` in `this.props.todos`

Comment: So in the render method I can use without problem `this.state.tasks` -> from constructor and `this.props.todos` from redux and there will be no conflict?

Comment: I dont think there should be any, can you create a codesandbox or stackblitz of your problem ? I am assuming the issue is elsewhere